# How to whitelist page from Google Mobile Usability issues check?

Tags: google-search-console, html, mobile, usability

My site has a page that admittedly only looks good on desktop.
How can I tell Google Search Console "Thanks for the Mobile Usability issues warnings, no need to tell me again about this particular page."

No, there is no way to make it mobile friendly. (OK, maybe with fancy javascript.)

Yes, I still want it to be indexed in search engines.